# Can anyone else use let statements at their Node.js REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-harmony

Is it possible? It doesn't seem to work in my REPL, neither with nor without `--harmony`.

What I'd really like to do is use for..of loops, but let seems a simpler thing to troubleshoot and is likely the same reason.

Anyone know anything about the status of these?

Comment: hey can you mark the answer on this question?

Answer (score 8):

```
$ node --version
v0.10.13
```

It was a bit cryptic, you'd think just `--harmony` would work, but you need to add in a `use strict` somewhere (which you can do at the command line):

```
$ node --harmony --use-strict
> var letTest = function () {
...   let x = 31;
...   if (true) {
.....     let x = 71;  // different variable
.....     console.log(x);  // 71
.....   }
...   console.log(x);  // 31
... }
undefined
> letTest()
71
31
undefined
>
```

Much happy!

However, I tried a simple `of` comprehension and it didn't work:

`[ square(x) for (x of [1,2,3,4,5]) ]`

With no luck. It looks like you may have to [go past the current stable release](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ES6-%28a.k.a.-Harmony%29-Features-Implemented-in-V8-and-Available-in-Node) to get all the harmony features.

Comment: @user568109 where did you find that? I had a hard time finding that info, mostly because one of the keywords is "of"

Comment: NodeJS uses V8 engine. V8 compatibility is listed here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 1):

If you run it from a file, node.js will tell you the error :

```
SyntaxError: Illegal let declaration outside extended mode
```

Its details are given in another question [What is extended mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253509/what-is-extended-mode) As it happens the extended mode is built on strict mode so you can't use it without `"use strict"` and harmony flag both. The reason I will quote from [here](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2011-December/018903.html):

> Recall that ES5 defines "strict mode", a new mode of execution for JS.
>   Let's call the other mode "classic mode".  ES6 defines a third
>   "extended mode", which builds on strict mode, and enables the new
>   features.

The recent node v11.7 has iterators which allow you to use `for of` loops. Example I used :

```
function* fibonacci() {
    let prev = 0, curr = 1, temp;
    for (;;) {
        temp = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = temp + curr;
        yield curr;
    }
}

for (let n of fibonacci()) {
    if (n > 1000)
        break;
    console.log(n);
}
```

For now, I could only use `for of` over iterators and not simple arrays.

Comment: It is actually not needed to add the 'use strict' pragma to the code. Just the flag along with harmony