# How to test harmony / ES6 / ECMAScript 6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, intern, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

As per the title, I'm trying to test some AMD modules written in ES6 JS, running from *nodejs*.

I tried first with [*Intern*](http://theintern.io/): even after enabling `--harmony` in nodejs, I ended up facing Intern's dependency chain, where I was not able to enable Harmony in e.g. *Istanbul*, *esprima* and others (I opened an [issue](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/282) for that).

I then moved onto [*mocha*](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/), and here I'm stuck ... *strangely*. I enabled Harmony both for nodejs and mocha itself, here's the `package.json` test script:

```js
"test": "node --harmony node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\mocha tests --harmony --recursive"
```

that I run from command prompt as `npm test my_test_folder`. Still, some ES6 constructs (like `const`) pass ok, but then it chokes on destructuring assignment. Here are the first output lines:

```
const { log, dir } = require('../consoleLogger.js');
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    [...continues...]
```

I've also checked this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177776/how-can-i-write-and-test-ecmascript-6-es6-code-now) and heard about transpilers, <strike>but I don't really know if they could work</strike> and I'm now trying to make transpilers work in this case.

Any idea on how to solve this, without resorting to change all ES6 bits spread in code? TA.

Comment: Are you able to use any of harmony's features when not using Mocha? If it does not work when you are not using Mocha, it won't work with Mocha.

Comment: Good point, although the code is part of a Thunderbird plugin, where harmony features are working. Here I'm trying to run tests from (node) command line, so issues come out now.

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it, check out http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 does not implement destructuring yet, so it won't be available in node for a while. Block scoping (including const) is mostly implemented, but be aware that a pre-ES6 version of const was always available, so you might want to double check what you are actually observing -- you could try 'let' declarations for less ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. At the very beginning I just tried running mocha (so with *plain* node) and I got error on `const`. Then I enabled `--harmony` when invoking node, and I moved forward to the next issue. Anyway, I'm trying to go for transpiling to ES5 before running mocha.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using

```sh
npm install mocha-traceur

mocha ./tests/* --compilers js:mocha-traceur
```

and it's been working like a charm !

Comment: thanks, I'll try that as soon as I get again so crazy to dive into Thunderbird development :)