# Why "let" es6 harmony works only with use strict?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, let, use-strict

This code:

```
var x = 8,
    y = 12;

let ( x = 5, y = 10) {
   return x + y;
}
```

..gives "SyntaxError: Illegal let declaration outside extended mode"

But with "use strict" it works fine.

So it's interesting why 'let' first integrated with "use strict" mode ? (according to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#nodeharmony)

Comment: What are you using to transpile? And/or what node version?

Comment: Works for me in FF (nightly)

Comment: @loganfsmyth node v0.11.14

Comment: As far as I know, the reason is because people wanted to have a clear separation between older code and newer code, and the easiest way to do that would be to have "use strict" mark newer code. This is called [`Extended mode`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253509/what-is-extended-mode). That said, I'm not actually sure if this is part of the final spec or just the current implementations.

Comment: Note however that the form of `let` your are using, the [`let expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_expressions) is a non-standard style supported only in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

`let` is not a reserved word in ES3-era JavaScript. For instance, you could do this:

```
var let = 5;
```

which would declare a variable called `let`. The ES5 spec was forward looking, and made keywords they expected to use in the future reserved inside strict mode functions. So in the ES6 world, they can parse `let` as a keyword, but only inside strict containers. Outside strict containers, backwards compatibility demands that `let` be treated as an identifier, not a keyword.